# Firebase cloud message - head up notifcation, android and ios

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase notifications, with flutter. I want the notification to be a heads-up notification. After much research, on Android this is possible when the app is in the background, only by using, "data" when sending the notification, not "notification". So I send it like this:

```
   "to": "/topics/all",
        
  "data": {
    "title": "Alert",
    "body": "App maintanance is underway.",
     
   }
```

and it works great.

However, I am also sending messages to ios devices. Now with iOS, the "notification" field has to be in the notification, otherwise the notification will not show up.

The problem is that when I add the "notification" field to the request, on Android the notification is shown up twice. Once due to "notification", and once because I manually display the notification as I customised, to make it pop up.

So when I send the message like this:

```
{
    "to": "/topics/all",
        
  "data": {
    "title": "Alert",
    "body": "App maintanance is underway.",
     
   }

  "notification": {
     "title": "Alert",
    "body": "App maintanance is underway.",
     
   }


}
```

It comes into android twice.

Now I could make two topics, one for Android and one for iOS, but sometimes I send messages to specific devices with token, and I don't know if its an Android device or iOS.

How can I cater for both?

Thanks

Here is my flutter code:

```
const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel', // id
    'High Inportance Notifications', // title
    'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
    playSound: true,
    importance: Importance.high,

    );

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('A message just showed up, id: ${message.messageId}');

  showNotification(message);    // without this it isn't heads-up when in background

}


Future<void> setUpFirebaseMessaging(BuildContext context) async {

  print('2124: setUpFirebaseMessaging');

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(
      _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize;

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance
      .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );


  // subscribe to topic on each app start-up
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('all');

  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((value) {
    String token = value;
    print('2124: Firebase Token: ${token}');
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {

    print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
    // print('Message data: ${message.data}');

    RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
    // AndroidNotification android = message.notification.android;
    // AndroidNotification data = message.data;

    // print('hashCode ${notification.hashCode}');
    print('title ${message.data['title']}');
    print('body ${message.data['body']}');

    // if (notification != null) {
    if (message.data != null) {

    showNotification(message);



    };


  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published');
    RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
    AndroidNotification android = message.notification.android;

    if(notification != null && android != null){
      showDialog(context: context, builder: (_){
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(notification.title),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(notification.body)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
    }
  });
}

void showNotification(RemoteMessage message) {

  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      message.hashCode,
      message.data['title'],
      message.data['body'],
      // message.notification.title,
      // message.notification.body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          channel.description,
          color: Colors.blue,
          playSound: true,
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
          icon: '@drawable/ic_stat_output_onlinepngtools',
        ),
      ));


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the **showNotification** function from **_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler** as it triggers its own notification (from local_notification package) and firebase messaging package has its own notification so we have two!!